# Is there something wrong with PHP OR operator?

Tags: php

My dump variables appear on their pages:

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '44.71.45.98' OR '44.71.45.99') {
  //blah blah
}else{
  //blah
}
```

I know this is wrong but when I tried..it's working to my another computer.It didn't prompt me an error even if i know that this is wrong...

Usually I code or like these:

```
//this is correct
if(isset($a) or isset($b)){

}
```

Comment: Sure it is working on another computer.. It's because second part of your expression, `'44.71.45.99'` always evaluates to `true`. You need to compare it to something.

Comment: you should have learn some very basic programming knowledge and then try to do programming.

Comment: @mocca Attempting to explain why your question has received so many downvotes: This is something that can be found on any of the most basic PHP tutotials. Knowing about the use of multiple conditions with logical operators is essential to a large proportion of programming languages. As this is the case, your question could be construed as "not showing any research effort". Hope that helps.

Comment: @brenda I know it was wrong.I'm 6 years in computer programming.I add a note after that question.This is what happens when someone ask a very basic question(s).Thought it was the same with C++.

printf( "%d" , (x == w || x == y || x == z) );

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it should be:

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '44.71.45.98' or $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '44.71.45.99') ...
```

'or' (or '||') groups together boolean (true or false) expressions (such as the comparisons using '=='). In your original code, it was converting the second IP string to a boolean -- the value true -- so the if statement would *always* match.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '44.71.45.98'
OR
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '44.71.45.99'
)
```

Comment: I already tried that yesterday...And I receive an error..
I tried this...
<pre>
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '44.71.45.98' OR $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '44.71.45.99')
</pre?

Comment: remove that pre...if you test that to your php versions you see what i mean...$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '44.71.45.98' OR '44.71.45.99' this didn't prompt me an error...I don't get it...

Comment: it is not correct, non empty strings are evaluated to true, so basically you will get if(false OR true) and the code will be executed

Answer (score 3):

Your expression is not correct. It should be like this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '44.71.45.98' OR
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '44.71.45.99')
```

Or how this is done by 99% of developers:

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '44.71.45.98' ||
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '44.71.45.99')
```

Comment: I use OR rather than || because of this...
OR executes my hello world in 2.6941299438477E-5
|| executes my hello world in 2.7894973754883E-5

Comment: @mocca there is no performance difference, what you take as a difference is just random noise and inaccuracy because you executed the code only once, with a lot of other processes being executed on your computer at the same time... These are *absolutely* not reliable results.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use an array of IPs (if more than one)

```
if(in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('44.71.45.98', '44.71.45.99', etc))
```

Answer (score 2):

here you need to use logical OR operator..

your code should be like this..

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '44.71.45.98' || $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '44.71.45.99'){
    code if condition is true..
}
else{
  code if condition is false..
}
```

can do it by this way too..

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '44.71.45.98' or $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '44.71.45.99')
```

Answer (score 2):

Here I prefer to use || as OR operator. The code should be:

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '44.71.45.98' || $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '44.71.45.99')
```

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel Who comments like that? A new user trying to answer a question. Constructive criticism is helpful. Yours is, in fact, the complete opposite of helpful.

Comment: @BrendanBullen if you can't read, I am not commenting this nonsense answer but ones who upvoted it.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel Comments aren't a place for these sorts of discussions but I will say that a response (in all caps) highlighting an answer in a negative way is unnecessary and brash. Considering your reputation, I'd have thought you would know better than to post such an unhelpful comment.

Comment: comments arent' supposed to be helpful. it's just comments.

Comment: I fixed my answer. Thanks to @BrendanBullen for your kind comments.